# windows service inserts wrong date format in few machines

Tags: c#, .net, sql, date, windows-services

I have created one windows services which inserts data from .mdb (Microsoft access file) to sql(MS sql 2008) table but while inserting date service inserts wrong date in few machines only
e.g.
correct insertion into sql is 2013/06/01 and
wrong insertion into sql is 2013/01/06

I have checked the date format of machines and sql server also but no success yet
I don't know why it is inserting wrong date in few machines only even date format is kept same

Comment: Show your code: It looks like your code takes the date through a String transformation using different regional settings. Also make sure you fix the code, don't change the Regional Settings!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".